# If I use select() polling method, should I set sockets to non-blocking?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am using the select() polling function to determine when there is data to be read from a socket.  I am doing this so that I do not have to rely on blocking functions like accept() and recv().  Since select() blocks until the file handle has data, is it necessary to set the sockets to non-blocking using fcntl()?

It seems to me that it is not necessary, since the select() function tells me that data is ready to be read from the socket file handle.

I have seen code in which the programmer has used select() and has also set sockets to non-blocking, and I have seen code in which the programmer has used select and has left the blocking settings in place.  Which is correct?  Is there an advantage to using select() and setting sockets to non-blocking?

Comment: It of course depends on your use case, but in my experience, if you want to do anything more serious than a basic example, non-blocking sockets are the way to go. You can also use multiple threads, but then still I'd lean towards using non-blocking sockets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should in general set the sockets to non-blocking. Here's why:

- When writing to sockets, the fact that you can write to the socket does not necessarily mean you can write all you want to the socket without blocking. Hence a write to a socket might block if you have a large amount of data to write to the socket, but the socket buffer only has space for a smaller amount.
- When reading from sockets, the fact there is data to be read from the socket does not necessarily mean there will be all the data there that you want (though it will return a short read if you do).

If you are only writing or reading one byte at a time, I suppose that would be an exception, but it is a rare exception.

Comment: Reading from a socket does not block if the whole buffer provided by the user cannot be filled. It will simply fill in what it can - it doesn't matter whether the socket is non-blocking or not.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I thought that if `O_NONBLOCK` is not set, then a write *may* block or may complete as a short write. IE you cannot guarantee it won't block. Is that not correct? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html says *"If the O_NONBLOCK flag is clear, a write request may cause the thread to block, but on normal completion it shall return nbyte."*

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right - I was talking about *reading*, not *writing*. I agree with you about the writes. Your first bullet about reads seems incorrect to me for the reason I mentioned.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves - doh. Yes you are quite right. Fixed.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves You're both wrong about the `write()` in blocking mode. It must block until all data is transferred. The Posix specification requires it.

Comment: @EJP that's not quite true. What happens if (e.g.) a signal arrives after writing some of the data?